# replace reinterpret_cast by unions in constexpr - good idea?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, unions

I am using this code to convert a pointer to a `size_t`, it is used in a  `::std::hash` function that should hash a given pointer at compile time, and since `reinterpret_cast`s are not allowed in `constexpr`, I came up with the following solution, it works as expected but I want to know whether this can be considered a good idea.
It would also be great if you could give me a few pointers on how portable this piece of code actually is.

```
union {
   size_t datr;
   void* pointer;
} dummy{.pointer = (void*) somePointer};
size_t pointerAsAsize_t = dummy.datr; // how portable is this?
```

Is there any better solution - as stated above, I want to create a `::std::hash<some_pointer*>` that runs at compile time.

Comment: Can you test on more than one compiler and platform?

Comment: Given that `.pointer` is set but never read it might be possible that the compiler never bothers to set it at all because it can assume you never read from `.datr` unless you wrote to it first.

Comment: "it works as expected" Not within constant evaluation (e.g. template argument, constexpr variable initializer), I believe.

Comment: Pointer values are generally not known at compile time. It isn't clear how you plan to hash unknown values.

Comment: [Accessing an inactive union member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attempt to perform that in a constant expression context (ie: when the compiler is forced to call your code at compile time, such as the expression leading to an array size or a template argument), you will find that it will not compile. Constexpr execution requires that anything which would provoke UB at compile time will instead be ill-formed. And since your code provokes UB (by accessing a union member which is not active), it will fail to compile.

[All three major compilers will fail on this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/89jkzo) in a constant-expression context. MSVC (surprisingly) gives the best, most direct error message:

> (13): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant 
>   (9): note: failure was caused by accessing a non-active member of a union
>   (9): note: see usage of 'foo::Foo::integer'

Your code probably "works as expected" only because you're calling it when the compiler doesn't have to execute it at compile-time. Given GCC/Clang's errors, if you used it as the array size for an array on the stack, it probably invoked GCC/Clang's variable-length array language extension. If you turned that off, your code would likely not compile. My example made it a global array, which doesn't allow VLAs.

---

> Is there any better solution

Nope. Even [C++20's `bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) will not be `constexpr` if you provide a pointer (or a type containing pointers) as either the source or destination. Compile-time pointers are real things, not just numbers that represent addresses; converting them to/from integers is simply not a reasonable activity at compile-time.

Compile-time pointers have to point to things that exist at compile-time. There is *no way* to know where they will point at *runtime*. So the idea of hashing the compile-time value of a pointer (even a pointer to a static/global object) is just doomed from the start.

Answer (score -2):

I think on most of the plaftorms this code will work, however formally it can not.
`size_t` is an unsigned type to hold the result `sizeof(xxx)` constructrion. There is no guarantee that is is big enough to store a pointer. You can add `static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void*),"")` or use `std::intptr_t` if it's available in your library.

Comment: Its undefined behaviour to read from any `union` member except the last one to have been assigned to. Changing `datr`'s typd is not enough.